# How to reproduce an existing html design with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am asked to reproduce this design with bootstrap.
Original design below

[image]

and this is the Html code of the Original design

```
<style type="text/css">td img {display: block;}</style>

    <table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1280">

      <tr>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="684" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="97" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="31" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="61" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="83" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="105" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="216" height="1" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td colspan="10">





               <img src="moza-slider/sliders/1.jpg" width="1280" height="532">



       </td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="532" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>




      <tr>
       <td rowspan="2" colspan="6"><img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c1" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c1.jpg" width="815" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c1" alt="" /></td>
       <td colspan="3"><img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c7" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c7.jpg" width="249" height="1" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c7" alt="" /></td>
       <td rowspan="2"><img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c10.jpg" width="216" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="images/decoupes/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Now in order to use bootstrap and make it responsive, i took the 4 main slice leaving aside the spacer.gif and use them with bootstrap like this

```
<div class="container">


<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12  text_blanc"> 



<img src="moza-slider/sliders/1.jpg" width="1280" height="532"> 





 <div class="col-md-6 bg_black text_blanc black_menu_top"> 


   <a class="page-scroll text_blanc" href="#ojm1">HOME</a>


   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

    <a class="page-scroll text_blanc" href="#ojm2">WHO WE ARE</a>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

   <a class="page-scroll text_blanc" href="#ojm3">WHAT WE DO</a>

     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

      <a class="page-scroll text_blanc" href="#ojm4">THE PORTFOLIO</a>

      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 


      <a class="page-scroll text_blanc" href="#ojm5">THE EVENTS</a>


       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 



      <a class="page-scroll text_blanc" href="#ojm6"> REACHING US </a>



        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</div>

<div class="col-md-3"> 
 <img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r3_c7" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r3_c7.jpg" width="249" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r3_c7" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-3"> 
<img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c10.jpg" width="216" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" alt="" />
</div>



 </div>


</div> 










</div>
```

**Problem**

When I reproduce the design with bootstrap this is what I get
[image: Result with Bootstrap]

As you can see there is a white space at the bottom right of this meanwhile there is no space on the original design.

**Question :**

**How to make the white space down the image disappear an make it look exactly like the original design like on the image below ?**

[image]

> > **Here is a demo of the [Bootstrap version](http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/bootstrap_version.php) (the one i have to correct)**

Comment: Can you be more specific with respect to what you want?

Comment: Please look at the two images and see that there is a white space at the left side of the images that came with bootstrap. My question is how to reproduce the same thing that I had with the tables without having any space at the left in the corner as you can see there is a space on the second image ? How to solve that with bootstrap ?

Comment: so you just want the nav positioned in the centre? try using padding

Comment: Please create a demo of the problem.

Comment: This is a demo of the bootstrap version that I have to modify and adjust to look like the original design
http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/bootstrap_version.php

Comment: @Totoro I want the nav bar to cover the down of the top image just like on the original image. There should not be any white space at the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to put the three bottom columns inside a .row like:

```
<div class="row">
  col-md-6 bg_black text_blanc black_menu_top>...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then you need to give your image a class. for example `.imgFull` and add this css rule:

```
.imgFull { width: 100% }
```

Comment: Tks. It is getting better HOWEVER now i think due to the new row it has moved the top content to the right side a little bit. Please check out this screenshoot and let me know what I should do. Tks

[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/bESQQkC.png)

Comment: Do you have an idea of how i can do what you said and yet it will be perfectly adjusted ? Because I can tell that adding a row is very important

Comment: You need to put a div with background-color: black inside the col-md-6 and remove background-color from the col-md-6

Comment: I think you are the exact definition of a genius.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the fixed width by changing the inline attribute of the img.

As the background image isn't really fitting I would suggest you use a dark color as background and add some opacity as you see fit.

You should change the "width" attribute of :

```
<img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c10.jpg" width="216" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" alt="">
```

Something around 250 should be close to the original file.

Regards,
-Gallo

Comment: You did not tell me what I should change the inline attribute of the image to. What am i supposed to replace the inline attribute with ?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot share images due to my rating.

You should change the "width" attribute of :

<img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" src="images/decoupes/iimajin-new-worked-on_r2_c10.jpg" width="216" height="162" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r2_c10" alt="">

Something around 250 should be close to the original file.

Comment: @Gallo: at the very least add that to your answer then.

Comment: @Gallo  I did that , I changed the width but still the left side is now the problem when i maintain "container" . Please check out a demo at http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/brouillons.php

 But when i switch to container-fluid, it becomes worse.